# Visual Studio 2015 RC Community Edition Target Platform set to Windows 10 TP on Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I just freshly installed Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2015 RC Community Edition.

The compilation of an existing c++ project failed, not finding `<windows.h>` for include. In order to fix that I installed Windows 8.1 SDK with no luck.

Looking into it my Project Settings for the "Win32" configuration says:

[image: Project Settings]

Why does VS2015 display Windows 10 as default target platform and why can't I change the value to Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation of

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Windows 10 (Technical Preview)

and

- Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.10069

seems to be done by default during Visual Studio 2015 RC setup.

The optional selection of `Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools` does not seem to install the respective Platform Toolsets properly alongside of the Windows X versions in order to be able to change that on the respective project settings page.

Uninstalling the above mentioned Tool- and SDK-Kits for Windows 10 made

```
Target Platform    Windows
```

available in the Project Settings and I can choose Version 8.1 now.

Now `<windows.h>` is found again.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Properties]

I had the same problem.
I changed the platform toolset to v140_xp, and closed VS2015. After opening VS2015 asked to install Windows XP C++ libraries, 225MB. After these steps my project was compiled successfully. Hope this helps you.